# Python | Tkinter : Move multiple and different objects to gether

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, canvas, motion

I have searched a lot but, I couldnt find the exact answer whats I need ( or I couldnt understand properly ).
In my code there are 1 rectangle, 8 lines. They are moving synchronously. But I want to add a bunch of circles in my canvas. To do that, Im creating a lot of row ''create_oval'' objects. This is meaningless because in next step may be I need  thousand of balls in the canvas. I have tried a lot of loops, etc. to find a way to create circles with shortened method but I couldn't achieve what I need.
This my codes.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

tk = Tk()




W, H =600, 500

canvas = Canvas(tk, width=W, height=H)
canvas.pack()

rectangle= canvas.create_rectangle(50, 250, 550, 50, fill="blue")

line1 = canvas.create_line(370, 70, 550,70,fill="black")
line2 = canvas.create_line(330, 90, 550,90,fill="black")
line3 = canvas.create_line(290, 110, 550,110,fill="black")
line4 = canvas.create_line(250, 130, 550,130,fill="black")
line5 = canvas.create_line(210, 150, 550,150,fill="black")
line6 = canvas.create_line(170, 170, 550,170,fill="black")
line7 = canvas.create_line(130, 190, 550,190,fill="black")
line8 = canvas.create_line(90, 210, 550,210,fill="black")

line9 = canvas.create_line(50, 230, 550,230,fill="black")


ball1 = canvas.create_oval(550,50,545,55, fill="red")
ball2 = canvas.create_oval(550,50,545,55, fill="red")
ball3 = canvas.create_oval(550,50,545,55, fill="red")
ball4 = canvas.create_oval(550,50,545,55, fill="red")
ball5 = canvas.create_oval(550,50,545,55, fill="red")
ball6 = canvas.create_oval(550,50,545,55, fill="red")
ball7 = canvas.create_oval(550,50,545,55, fill="red")
ball8 = canvas.create_oval(550,50,545,55, fill="red")

Xspeed = 10
Yspeed = 0




def moveTable():

    global Xspeed,Yspeed    

    canvas.move(table, Xspeed, Yspeed)

    canvas.move(line1, Xspeed, Yspeed)
    canvas.move(line2, Xspeed, Yspeed)
    canvas.move(line3, Xspeed, Yspeed)
    canvas.move(line4, Xspeed, Yspeed)
    canvas.move(line5, Xspeed, Yspeed)
    canvas.move(line6, Xspeed, Yspeed)
    canvas.move(line7, Xspeed, Yspeed)
    canvas.move(line8, Xspeed, Yspeed)
    canvas.move(line9, Xspeed, Yspeed)


    canvas.move(ball1, Xspeed-randint(5,10),Yspeed+randint(5,10))
    canvas.move(ball2, Xspeed-randint(5,10),Yspeed+randint(5,10))
    canvas.move(ball3, Xspeed-randint(5,10),Yspeed+randint(5,10))
    canvas.move(ball4, Xspeed-randint(5,10),Yspeed+randint(5,10))
    canvas.move(ball5, Xspeed-randint(5,10),Yspeed+randint(5,10))
    canvas.move(ball6, Xspeed-randint(5,10),Yspeed+randint(5,10))
    canvas.move(ball7, Xspeed-randint(5,10),Yspeed+randint(5,10))
    canvas.move(ball8, Xspeed-randint(5,10),Yspeed+randint(5,10))

    left,top,right,bot = canvas.coords(table)
    if(left == 60 or left == 40):
        Xspeed = -Xspeed
    
    canvas.after(100, moveTable)


moveTable()

tk.mainloop()
```

It's probably very simple but I couldn't see it.

Comment: Does all lines had to be moved out of rectangle while the balls is dropping from top to bottom on right side?

Answer (score 1):

If you assign a tag to one or more widgets, you can affect them all at the same time.

Here's an example that moves all of the red items vertically, and all of the green items horizontally, all using only two `move` commands:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, background="black", width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

for i in range(20):
    x = random.randint(10, 110)
    y = random.randint(10, 110)
    width = random.randint(10, 30)
    height = random.randint(10, 30)
    canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+width, y+height, fill="red", tags=("red",))
    canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+width, y+height, fill="green", tags=("green",))

def animate():
    canvas.move("red", 0, 1)
    canvas.move("green", 1, 0)
    canvas.after(20, animate)

animate()
root.mainloop()
```

You could also just save the items to a list and iterate over the list

```
items = []
for i in range(100):
    item = canvas.create_oval(...)
    items.append(item)
...
for item in items:
    canvas.move(item, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, if I want to create thesee balls in a loop; I mean that the after 1 second create same balls from the same coordinates while the rectangle and the previous balls are still moving in their coordinates.I tried while and for loops but I didn't achieve.